# How would one implement custom themes into a website that is not wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, php-7

So i'm building a website in PHP7, HTML5, CSS3, JQuery, JavaScript5 not WordPress to be clear. One feature i would like is to allow users to change their theme to something that is not default theme so how would one do this i mean making the theme and implementing them? Would it just be an element say a drop down box with CSS documents or something else?
p.s. my other questions did not go down well so if this does not make sense or is unclear please let me know so i can improve it.

Comment: There are any number of ways one could design a "theme" mechanism. The question is too broad for Stack Overflow, I'm afraid.

Comment: Okay how broad is too broad for Stack Overflow as I've seen very very broad questions on here? Also what would be one to add a theme system? could you just use JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get your question exactly. But these are my opinions.
Generally , Custom Themes are added using themes(Non Wordpress) which you can download from sites like themeforest , envato market ,template.net etc. Either you can tweak it and make it your own or just use as it is. But if you do so please do have a glance at the licensing to avoid future problems.

And Dropdown menu can be made using CSS and JavaScript. I would say that its not a must. Its the content which makes it notable.

Comment: Okay thank you i will have a look  and i will also improve my question if its difficult to read as i'd rather not get blocked from asking questions

Comment: I would but i don't have enough reputation to up vote but alright do you have any free ones i could use they all seem to be paid alternatively could i not make the themes my self and have them be changeable by users?

Comment: Ok google is normally the awnser haha but yeah ill have a look

Comment: difficulty's hmm does being banned from asking questions count? I'm genuinely considering going somewhere else like Reddit as this whole getting down voted is happening too much like whats wrong with my questions iv'e given the problem.

Comment: okay so i wrote a little test JavaScript to see if i could achieve what i wanted and i can but how would i apply it globally to all pages without having to have the user re-select the theme each time?